# 502 Bad Gateway, Django, Nginx, Gunicorn, Postgresql, Virtualenv

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have been on this for a week now. I've been trying to deploy a little test app on digital ocean and I have followed many tutorials like this one:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn

I even tried the one click install tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image

And last night i tried this one which i found to be the most recent one:
http://franklevering.me/blog/how-deploy-your-django-app-postgresql-nginx-and-gunicorn

when i go to my IP: http://188.166.62.146 I get a Welcome to nginx! page.
And when i go to  http://188.166.62.146:8001 i get a 400 Bad Request.

I run the following command:

```
gunicorn --log-file=- blog.wsgi:application

[2015-02-20 07:02:55 +0000] [6089] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-02-20 07:02:55 +0000] [6089] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (6089)
[2015-02-20 07:02:55 +0000] [6089] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-02-20 07:02:55 +0000] [6094] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6094
```

in /var/log/nginx i get this error repeated:

```
2015/02/20 03:07:27 [error] 4755#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.128.91.3, server: 188.166.62.146, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", u$$.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/favicon.ico", host: "188.166.62.146"
```

This is my settings.py file:

```
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False


import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'blog',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    }
}
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Nicosia'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/blogger/blog/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

And here is my configuration file in etc/nginx/sites-available/blogger :

```
server {
    server_name project.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/blogger/blog/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

I used the current command for binding gunicorn:

```
blog.wsgi:application --bind 188.166.62.146:8001
```

/opt/blogger/blog# gunicorn blog.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001

```
[2015-02-20 13:02:37 +0000] [7922] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-02-20 13:02:37 +0000] [7922] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8001 (7922)
[2015-02-20 13:02:37 +0000] [7922] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-02-20 13:02:37 +0000] [7927] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7927
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gunicorn blog.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001
```

/opt/blogger/blog# `bg`

```
[1]+ gunicorn blog.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Comment: An IP address is not a server name.

Comment: Thank you Daniel that fixed the Gateway 502 error. But now i get to a homepage displaying: Welcome to nginx! when i go to 188.166.62.146:8001 i get a bad request 400

Comment: Did you link `/etc/nginx/sites-available/blogger` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blogger` and remove the default ` /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` ? You'll also need to restart Nginx after doing so.

Comment: @andrewsomething yes, I did. What exactly do you mean with linking them? I have in both sites-enebled and sites-available the same file. I deleted the default from both and restarted nginx. Nothing changed

Comment: @ Tony Kyriakidis try setting debug = True, if it works, then try messing around with the ALLOWED_HOSTS when you set debug to False. Notice in the tangowithDjango link you provided section "16.5.4. Turning off DEBUG Mode"

Comment: I meant to say 16.5.4 at this link http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/deploy.html

Comment: or try debug = False and change ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]  if that works, then you know is has to do with these settings. Although using the * for allowed hosts is not good as per the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your nginx server name to your IP address.

Then bind gunicorn to 127.0.0.1:8001.

The deal is, nginx, as far as I know, will forward, all incoming requests from server name to proxy_pass variable. Then make gunicorn answer requests to where you've pointed proxy_pass.

Comment: would this still work when you use multiple domains on the same ip-address? (how?)

Comment: Sure.
1) Make sure each nginx entry is being accepted on a different port (reverse proxy)
2) Make each nginx entry answer to a specific DNS name. site A answers to example.com, site B answers to coolexamples.com - this should be configured in server_Name directive.